# How to compare to different TimeValue in Java?

Tags: java

how it is possible to compare two different time value in java, which was saved as string value?

I have these two values:

```
String startTime = "11:23";
String endTime = "22:22";
```

Now it is important for my application to evaluate, which of these two values is higher than the other one. This code is not possible and i have only the possibility to save these two time values as strings:

```
if(startTime > endTime){
       // do some stuff
} else {
       // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the strings with SimpleDateFormat and compare the times, but for HH:mm format (or any descending, fixed length date/time format)  you can just compare the strings.

```
// assuming strings have the same padded format.
if(startTime.compareTo(endTime) > 0) // startTime is greater
```

Comment: what if start time is 11:55 and end time is 00:55; what will this return?

Comment: @Abhishek 00:55 is before 11:55 which is before 24:55, even if you parse the time.

Comment: there is no time as 24:55 :P

Comment: @Abhishek Ok, effectively 00:55 + 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Joda [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class

```
private LocalTime toTime(String time) {
    String[] t = time.split(":");
    return new LocalTime(t[0], t[1]);
}

int compared = toTime(startTime).compareTo(toTime(endTime));

boolean b = toTime(startTime).isBefore(toTime(endTime));

boolean b = toTime(startTime).isAfter(toTime(endTime));
```